# Add text to button with image HTML

Tags: html, css

I have a button which is initially an image and performs an action when clicked. However I want to add the title Submit to the button.

How could I do this?

```
<form name="input" action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="emailaddress" placeholder="email address" class=emailInput />
<button type="submit" style="border: 0; background: transparent">
    <img src="submit.png" width="50" height="31" class=submitButton alt="Submit" />
</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way is to do this with CSS since the image is actually a background for the text I suppose.

- **remove the image** from inside the button
- use **css** to decorate the button
- **place** the **text** in the button

css:

```
button {
    background:transparent url(submit.png) no-repeat left top;
    width:50px;
    height:31px;
}
```

[more here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp).